# Django autocomplete from db

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I have a model like this:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want to autocomplete an input in template according to this model's title field. I just want autocomplete for title anything else would not work for me? I think it should be done with jquery, ajax etc. I don't have any idea about them.
Is there any way to do this? Is there any packages for exact same thing?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify a little?

Comment: I have an input in template and I want to autocomplete titles when I user starts to type.

Answer (score 2):

[ui-autocomplete-input](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) works pretty well for this.

Generate the list in your template

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTitles = [
   {% for baslik in basliks %}
      "{{ baslik.title}}" {% if not forloop.last %},{% endfor %}   
   {% endfor %}

];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTitles
});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

**EDIT** (based on comments): Added a json response; this would be needed in both the ui-autocomplete and bootstrap/typeahead.js solution

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse

def json_response_view(request):
   q = request.GET.get('q', '')
   response_data = Baslik.objects.filter(title__startswith=q).values("title")
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I will have a huge db. Isn't this bad for huge dbs? Besides, is there any chance to use starts with with that?

Comment: really bad for big db ;)

Comment: In that case you might want to look at Remote JSON datasource on the same site: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote, and generate a view in your Django project that generates a json page with titles

Comment: I recommend using boostrap instead of the outdated jquery ui

Comment: Is there any chance to use my own search view? I have this code: `try:
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    except:
        q = False
    
    baslik_queryset = Baslik.objects.filter(
        Q(title__startswith=q)
    )`
How can I use this code to search and display results under the input for autocomplete simultaneously?

Comment: The additional json response is not required for ui-autocomplete or there is another usage for it. Besides I still don't have intended solution for my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I use bootstrap's typeahead plugin, with its Bloodhound engine that let's you use remote sources.
Docs and examples [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/).

You simple have to write a JSON response view that processes the request made by the typeahead

Edits needed for the js code:
You could use something like the following:

```
var source = new Bloodhound({
    hint: false,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('description'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL + '&query=%QUERY'
    });

    source.initialize();
```

This will initialize a source pointing to your JSON view. Please note that Bloodhound will fill the %QUERY parameter with wathever the user types.

After that, we need to tell the typeahead to use this source:

```
$(typeahead_input).typeahead(null, {
        name: 'some_name',
        displayKey: 'description',
        source: source.ttAdapter() }
```

Note the displayKey  I have specified, that's the attribute displayed by the typeahead, now, onto the view:

We will have something like:

```
from django.views.generic import View

class MyJsonView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        context = []
        querystring = request.GET.get('query', None)
        if querystring:
            instances = MyModel.objets.filter(somefield__icontains=querystring)
            for ins in instances:
                 context.append({'id': ins.id, 'description' ins.display_field})
        json_context = json.dumps(context)
        return HttpResponse(json_context, {'content_type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: I couldn't understand which part of the js code I should change. I am very new at js. Can you be more explanatory please?

Comment: Where should I put the `class MyJsonView(View):` and its continuation?

Comment: In a views.py file, in your app. You must point the url conf for YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL to this view

Comment: Let me understand this clear, I should put first and second code parts to base.html which I wanna use the search thing into, in between different <script> tags. Right? After that I should put the last code with `class MyJsonView(View)` to my views.py as a different view. And I should use a url configuration which I totally lost about how to do. How should I configure the urls.py?

Comment: That's some basic django knowledge!
add something like: url(r'^search_my_model/$', MyJsonView.as_view(), name='search_my_model')

Comment: Well, I did that and it raised an error `NameError at /
name 'View' is not defined`.

Comment: from django.views.generic import View

Comment: I used what you gave me but it is not auto completing right now.

Comment: Hi, i have a issue related to the typeahead bloodhound. I have to fetch suggestion list  from the database. I have to pass 2 value 1 from dropdown (category) and another will be the search text. the list get refereshed on change of dropdown value or search text. My ques is how can i pass 2 parameter and get it in my view.py file
remote: "/a_c/p_s/" + "?term=mobile&category=all",
this is how i'm passing value to the views.py

Comment: @sandeepnegi might be hard without seeing your code but if your request has `term` and `category` as url parameters, you should be able to get them in the view by name (if it still works like in this answer, eg: `requests.GET.get('term', None)`)

Comment: ok . actually the issue was in urls.py because of which the def was not called. but still thanx. i'm liking your ans.