# Trouble with Django and typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, typeahead.js

I'm trying to autocomplete from my db in an input with bloodhound of typeahead.js
I have models like this:

```
class Baslik(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I want this autocomplete according to this model's title field.

I put these js codes to my base.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // constructs the suggestion engine
var states = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  // `states` is an array of state names defined in "The Basics"
  local: $.map(states, function(state) { return { value: state }; })
});

// kicks off the loading/processing of `local` and `prefetch`
states.initialize();

$('#bloodhound .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'states',
  displayKey: 'value',
  // `ttAdapter` wraps the suggestion engine in an adapter that
  // is compatible with the typeahead jQuery plugin
  source: states.ttAdapter()
});

  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var source = new Bloodhound({
    hint: false,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('description'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL + '&query=%QUERY'
    });

    source.initialize();
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript">
      $(typeahead_input).typeahead(null, {
            name: 'some_name',
            displayKey: 'description',
            source: source.ttAdapter() }

      </script>
```

Also I have this input tag to autocomplete:

```
<form class="ui icon input" role="form" action="/baslik/">
   <div id="bloodhound">
      <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Ara..." id="input_lookup">
   </div>
   <i class="search link icon"></i>
   <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>
```

I have this view:

```
from django.views.generic import View
import json
class MyJsonView(View):

        def get(self, request):
            context = []
            querystring = request.GET.get('query', None)
            if querystring:
                instances = MyModel.objets.filter(somefield__icontains=querystring)
                for ins in instances:
                    context.append({'id': ins.id, 'description': ins.display_title})
            json_context = json.dumps(context)
            return HttpResponse(json_context, {'content_type': 'application/json'})
```

This is my url in my project's urls.py:

```
url(r'^search_my_model/$', MyJsonView.as_view(), name='search_my_model')
```

I don't know I made mistake in which part of these. How can I make this work? Any idea would help. Thanks.

Comment: Where is YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL defined?

Comment: In directory that settings.py placed at.

Comment: What was your point? I think I misunderstood it.

Comment: Is that text "YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL" actually present as such in your javascript code, or have you simply replaced your actual URL with some dummy text? And if that is actually literally there, then it is a variable: where in the JS is the value of the variable set?

Comment: Actually I don't have much idea about js part of these codes. I just used the codes in here... `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25412777/django-autocomplete-from-db/25413211?noredirect=1#comment39738982_25413211` So I don't know unfortunately. If you understand much than me about what to do with the answer in this link, please let me know.

Comment: Sigh. Even without knowing anything about javascript, it should be obvious that "YOUR_JSON_VIEW_URL" is a placeholder for your *actual* view URL. Otherwise how can the code know where to go to get the JSON content?

Comment: Well, it's obvious but without knowledge of javascript, I don't know what kind of url I should use instead of this placeholder. Should I put `/search_my_model/` or something else?